# What's wrong with my mutually exlusive radio input script?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, radio-button

It's not working, but if I comment out `uncheck.removeAttr('checked')`, it works! **Where am I going wrong?**

Little HTML as example:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="duration" checked="true" />
<select id="duration" class="duration">
    <option value="P30D">30 giorni</option>
    <option value="P1Y">365 giorni</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" name="type" value="interval" />
<select id="year">
    <?php foreach($years as $y) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $y->k; ?>">
    <?php echo $y->v; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

jQuery `click()` function event:

```
$('select').click(function() {

    var check   = $('input[type="radio"][value="duration"]');
    var uncheck = $('input[type="radio"][value="interval"]');

    if(!$(this).hasClass('duration')) {
        var old = check;
        check = uncheck;
        uncheck = old;
    }

    check.attr('checked', true); // Same: .attr('checked', 'checked')
    uncheck.removeAttr('checked');

})
```

Comment: You don't **need** to remove the 'checked' attribute from the other element. They're radio inputs with the same name - the mutual exclusivity will be handled by the browser anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
check.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so to answer you question, how to select the radio button when selecting a value from the selectbox you would have the following javascript:

```
$('select').click(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked'); // remove all checked from radio inputs
    $(this).prev('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', 'checked'); // checks the above radio button
});
```

Comment: sorry @Polmonino what is you exact goal then? Should the radio button be selected when you click on the select element?

Comment: Yes it should be checked on select click event. Even using your solution it's not working, it works only if i remove the line uncheck.attr()...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) in that case.